# How to optimize SQL Server query on a huge table

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a SQL Server database for storing information about ships. I have a table named "Position" with about 9 columns and 305 million records. I created a composite index (Non-Clustered) on columns "Resolution" and "DateTime". To give a bit of context, I have currently 2 values in "Resolution" (0 and 15) an they were imported in ascending order in the database.

When I do a query like this one (takes about 30 secondes to complete) :

```
SELECT TOP (1000) *
FROM [Position]
WHERE [Resolution] = 15 AND [DateTime] >= '2021-01-01';
```

[Estimated execution plan of the first query shown above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MA6Q.png)

SQL Server is not using the index I created even if it is faster by using it like this... (completes instantly):

```
SELECT TOP(1000) *
FROM [Position]
WITH(INDEX([IX_Position_Resolution_DateTime]))
WHERE [Resolution] = 15 AND [DateTime] >= '2021-01-01';
```

[Estimated execution plan of the second query shown above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkhe6.png)

I know that the composite index I created is probably not selective enought in the general case so it is ignored. But the performance issue is still there

So my question is: Why SQL Server is not using my composite index and how can I fix the performance issue working on this huge table?

Here is the stats for the index:

```
Statistics for INDEX 'IX_Position_Resolution_DateTime'.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                            Name                         Updated                            Rows                    Rows Sampled                           Steps                         Density              Average Key Length                    String Index
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 IX_Position_Resolution_DateTime             Nov  6 2023  9:34AM                       304830272                          766320                               2                               0                              18                             NO                                                        304830272                               0

                     All Density                  Average Length                         Columns
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                             0.5                               4                      Resolution
                    1.488671E-06                              14            Resolution, DateTime
                    1.290811E-06                              18        Resolution, DateTime, Id

                 Histogram Steps
                    RANGE_HI_KEY                      RANGE_ROWS                         EQ_ROWS             DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS                  AVG_RANGE_ROWS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                               0                               0                     2.12958E+08                               0                               1
                              15                               0                    9.187233E+07                               0                               1
```

My goal is to query the table using EntityFramework Core in C# and I don't want to specify the index to use every time. I know SQL Server is wait better than me for optimizing query but I don't understand why I have this problem.

I tried to create simple index on "Resolution" and "DateTime", updating statistics, reverse the order of my composite index. But nothing seems to works (still not using the index and query takes about 30 seconds to complete). The only time it is using my index is when I only select the key attribute in my query or when I explicitly request the use of the index.

This is my first question here, so any tips and tricks about posting, asking question, formatting, adding more details, etc. would be very appreciated :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I believe your question is better suited for https://dba.stackexchange.com/ site.

Comment: Using `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is fairly meaningless.  You should first figure out which `ORDER BY` clause you should be using, then reassess the execution plans.

Comment: For the first question it's much better than average (at least from what I notice).

Comment: Your index does not look likes its a covering index, so that might be an issue here. Also if you only have two values in "Resolution" then its not very selective.

Comment: select * is usually not good, since it needs to fetch a lot of columns. Also, if you have 50/50 of Resolution rows, it will still have to trawl through a lot.

Comment: So the index you created is like a separte copy of the data in the DB, then the Key lookup in the 2nd plan means it is going back to the original copy of the data and retrieving the rest of the columns as you are doing a select *, so for anyone to answer the question in a bit more detail - it would be good to post the full schema of the index you created. One way to solve key lookups is to include the required columns in the non-clustered index. BUT THAT IS NOT ALWAYS THE CASE

Comment: For me, I would get rid of the Clustered Index. I don't use them unless I truly have a need for them.

Comment: I'm no expert at SQL Server indexes at all, but the `Rows Sampled` value (766320) is way, way smaller than the `Rows` value (304830272). It looks like the index only has data on about **0.25%** of your rows. That might explain why SQL Server thinks it makes no sense to use the index. Then again, this is pure guesswork.

Comment: SQL Server decides "the amount of expected rows is so high that the number of key lookups isn't worth it, let's do a full scan instead". The solution is to 'cover' the query with the index i.e. make sure all columns selected are in the `INCLUDE` of the index. Don't do `SELECT *` just the columns you need. For further help, please share both polans using https://pastetheplan.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many people in the comment suggested and if you have a similar problem, creating a covering index by including the selected columns was the fix for me.

In case you have a huge table like mine, take a look at partitioned tables. It could help with the performance. It is something I will try when I have time to work on this project again.

Thanks for all the comments :)

Answer (score -1):

As other people suggest the problem could reside in `SELECT *` and in the fact that you doesn't really specify the key of secondary index.
Since youd didn't include other columns in your secondary index prefer to perform a table scan.

I suggest to try a different approach, using EF first define a query to return the identifiers of objects you need to retrieve, and then use this query to filter items in the table:

```cs
var ids = _dbContext.Positions.Where(_ => _.Resolution == 15 && _.DateTime > dateTime)
    .Select(_ => _.Id);

var items = _dbContext.Positions.Where(_ => ids.Contains(_.Id));
```